# Overloaded Start Routine function for class threads C++

Tags: multithreading, forms, dll, c++-cli

Using forms in a C++ DLL just to note. I'd thought this would be important as I need it to have the same variables as the Application has (which may or may not be different)

Starting my form I have to do this:

```
Form1 ^ ThisForm = gcnew Form1;
Application::Run(ThisForm);
```

Which is basic nothing to difficult. I get my form working fine upon use. Now I want to create a thread through Form1 (ThisForm). They are defined here:

```
public:
    VOID WINAPI MainThread2();
```

And all it does is set the label within this to the current time:

```
VOID Form1::MainThread2()
{
while (true)
{
    Beep(400, 100);
    time_t CurrentTime = time(0);
    struct tm* TimeStruct = localtime(&CurrentTime);
    string str = to_string(TimeStruct->tm_hour) + ":" + to_string(TimeStruct->tm_min) + ":" + to_string(TimeStruct->tm_sec);
    String^ timestring = gcnew String(str.c_str());

    this->label1->Text = "hello";
}
```

}

But obviously I can't create a thread with this:

```
CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ThisForm->MainThread2, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Due to this error:

```
error C2440: 'type cast': cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE'
```

How would I manage to start a thread through ThisForm

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you avoid the unmanaged thread APIs, and use the managed ones. This will let you use instance methods of managed classes, rather than just static C++ methods.

MSDN References:

- [Thread class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx?cs-lang=cpp)
- [Thread constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx3ezzs2.aspx?cs-lang=cpp)

---

If you really do want to use the unmanaged APIs, you need to make your thread method a static or global method (not instance, as you have it now). I don't remember off the top of my head if it's allowed to be a static method of a managed class; you may need to have it be a global method to make this work. (A static method of an unmanaged class would also work, but that doesn't buy you much.)

Comment: I attempted to do this:

Thread^ newThread

 ---- But updating any of the labels etc doesn't work inside the thread

Comment: That's not going to change by switching to the unmanaged APIs for starting the thread. There are several techniques for updating a WinForms API from a thread other than the UI thread, I'm sure you can find them by searching StackOverflow.